# Mobile test for local html files

Tags: html, mobile, ios-simulator, blackberry-simulator, wap

I have local html files that I need to know how they look like in various model of Nokia, Android, iPhone, Blackberry. Is there a way to do this? I google some online website for Nokia simulator but they are not working right. I need local test of html. If there is a free software that I can switch around in different phone (or separate software), it is perfect. I know this is not something new but I cannot find it.

Thanks again.

Comment: Are you on a Mac or PC? LOL... or does your username "HP" = Hewlett Packard? :)

Comment: No, HP is not Hewlett Packard lol... I am using PC. I have Visual Studio, Dreamweaver and all browsers

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Well, you can download all the relevant emulators (which you should be able to find via searching). Here we use Visual Studio which you can install the emulators into and run them from within the IDE, but if you don't already have VS it seems it won't be helpful for you. I suggest you just download all the relevant emulators.

Comment: I cannot seem to find the emulators. Where are they?

Comment: You mean in Visual Studio? Or just on the internet in general?

Comment: Well either in VS or Dreamweaver or anywhere. I just need a way to view html as it should look in the phone.

Comment: HP: Search on the web, you will find emulators easily. "<phone> Emulator". It will take a matter of seconds.

Answer (score -1):

Well iPhone uses safari so you can test in that

Comment: for Iphone it is simple but what about others